# PhpStorm: open source JS file instead of min file when Ctrl+Clicking

Tags: phpstorm, minify, file-watcher

I just started using File Watchers on PhpStorm to minify all my JavaScript in the project, and I've linked my docs already to the minified versions of the JS.

The problem I'm having now is I lost the ability to JUMP to the JS source code (function/method) directly by control clicking on the function name. Instead it jumps to the min.js file.

Is there a way I can set PhpStorm to open on the source JS instead of the min version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow [WEB-15474](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15474) for updates